# I can't center my logo image in the middle of my gray background image

Tags: css, reactjs, center, inline-styles

I can't get my logo to sit in the center of my gray background image. My logo will sit to the right of my gray background image or underneath, but it will not sit in the center of my gray image. I am building this application in React.js.

[Picture of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3XUDc.png)

[Picture of my code React.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/plhk9.png)

Comment: instead of attaching the pictures , try to paste the code on stackoverflow

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex) - **Images of code are not acceptable**

Comment: 1. Learn first how to ask a question related to implementation in StackOverflow.
2. Learn the differences about position: relative; and position: absolute;
3. Learn about margin: auto;
4. Learn the differences between a fixed height/width  or non-fixed height/width.
5. Learn, when and how CSS Flex works.

Answer (score -1):

The fist thing I've noticed is that you've used `{position:relative;}` in the background image, and that makes sense, but you've did the same to the other img which doesn't work, so the position of the second img should be `{position: absolute;}` then you can adjust the position using top, left, bottom and right
, hope that helped.